# When a mouse over the link ,create a preview of a website?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using tiptip and there is option of create a box when a link is mouseover.

So, the only way to do this is to get a screenshot of the html (how?) and using tiptip to do the popup preview, are there any way to do it more directly?

Since there are  >30 html website i need to create a preview, thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3162815/102937

Comment: Do you want to show an live preview of the page, or just a screenshot of the page? If you want to show a live preview, then you can [display the page in an iframe on mouseover.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16625709/975097)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than loading the webpage in an iframe (which could be very slow).

Why don't you just display an img screenshot of the site using an external API such as:

- http://www.thumbalizr.com/
- http://www.bitpixels.com/
- http://webshotspro.com/

Example:

http://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=http://www.google.com&width=250

Comment: what if the page is in localhost?

Comment: It will still work as long as you can provide a publicly accessible url. If it is an intranet site then you this approach won't work.

Comment: how about a large number of web, i have to do it one by one? thanks

Comment: Well if you want to save time, with some javascript you should be able to pull the href from the link tag and generate an img src from it.

Answer (score 1):

- Wherever it is applied, its been through a screen-shot only.
- That's a very optimized way and light. You you tooltip plugin is working fine with jquery, great or else, you can even try [Jquery's QTip plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).
- There are other ways of displaying the actual HTML by shortening it (in pixels), but can't consider them very light or say that are a less optimized solutions. (Also it has certain issues like not HTML for whatever reason or due to incompatibility didn't rendered well, whereas SS-Images always remains stable.)
- In practice, when you see google's search results, and in-place web-preview, you will find that they are actually using images.

Comment: what if the page is in localhost?

Comment: Well, is it to remain in localhost forever? or will it ever make to production on a independent domain? and secondly, even if its localhost, its less optimized.

Comment: how about a large number of web, i have to do it one by one? thanks

Comment: I know this is old thread but, one question @linuxeasy . WIll it still work if I assign a custom domain... say like project.local ?