# JavaScript/jQuery google style website preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, live-preview

I remember following a like off of here a little while ago for something called shark.js or sharpe.js (but I might be wrong on the name). I've tried googling it, looking through here, my browser history and I have had no luck. It wasn't wkhtmltopdf, I know that much. Does anybody know what it might be called or what I am talking about? Have you got a link to it please?

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow Question: [jQuery Webpage Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162815/jquery-webpage-preview)

From the second answer:
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail
That should be what your looking for, don't know if it's the exact same thing, but same functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at that earlier and also the other week and it wasn't quite what I was looking for. I should remember to bookmark things!

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I bookmark too many things and thus can never find what I'm looking for. In what ways is what you're looking for different, I might have some link or reference lying around.

Comment: I'm usually pretty good at bookmarking and organising them! It gave me a full size preview basically, generated on the fly, which I thought was pretty nifty as at was always the current page. Ah well, I'll make do with what I can find now I guess!

Comment: I went in and read some of the docs and source for the library above and you can define the container of the tool tip box. So, simply have your div set aside as the container. Don't know how well it would work to do exactly what you want (probably have to toy around with it a little), but it seems to have a relatively straight forward interface and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this can be done in client side javascript in real-time.  However, I bet Google uses a server-side process to capture a screenshot and then uses javascript to request an image to display to the client.