# Show web page previews on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to display previews of web pages when links are moused-over? I think such a feature would be very user-friendly (and it would make navigation much quicker). Would it be best to implement this by loading the "moused-over" page in some sort of frame, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: where do you see that? framesets are deprecated, but since when are iframes? and since when is HTML5 the only doctype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited of static (or almost static pages), do screenshots, and use images.

Otherwise, use this jquery plugin :

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail

Duplicate from : [jQuery Webpage Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162815/jquery-webpage-preview)

Comment: That question isn't a duplicate, but it's very similar. I'm also asking whether it's possible to show web page previews in a frame.