# Suggest me Jquery package for website preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a jquery package for website preview.

Website preview is basically when you add a website url inside input field, it should show brief description of that website with images (like facebook feed)

I have tried https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl. But it is not working properly in some cases.

Can any one suggest me a better package.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this is off-topic for SO. Honestly, I don't know where else you could ask this...

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want a preview of the live page, you'll have to use an iframe. If you just want an image preview, Fulvio's suggestion will work, but won't show a "live" preview (i.e., no animations that you would normally see, if the user is logged in to a page, you will only see the front page, etc). It is possible to actually scale the contents of an iframe so that it's a thumbnail, thus achieving the effect you want. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
#frame {
    zoom: 0.2;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<style>
#frame {
    width: 800px;
    height: 520px;
    border: none;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.2);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.bing.com">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Have fun :)

Copy and paste into your browser's URL bar to preview:

```
data:text/html,<html><head><!--[if IE]><style>iframe{zoom:0.2;}</style><![endif]--><style>iframe{width:800px;height:520px;border:none;-moz-transform:scale(0.2);-moz-transform-origin:0 0;-o-transform:scale(0.2);-o-transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform:scale(0.2);-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;}</style></head><body><iframe src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe></body></html>
```

From:

[jQuery Webpage Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162815/jquery-webpage-preview)

The easy way of doing it, is to use:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-For-URL-Live-Preview-urlive.html